# Обновление последней записи MySQL

Tags: mysql

Нужно обновить последнюю запись в таблице. Ключевое поле автоинкрементное. Есть код:

`mysql_query("UPDATE reports SET link=" . $otchetlink . " WHERE report_id=MAX(id)")`

Но он не работает. Как обновить запис ? Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:
`mysql_query("UPDATE reports SET link=" . $otchetlink . " ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")`
Должно обновить одну строку у которой самый большой `ID`

Comment: К сожалению - тоже самое, то есть ничего

Comment: Проблема была в синтаксисе запроса. Заменил `link=" . $otchetlink . " ` на `link='$otchetlink'` и все стало отлично. Вас отмечу как верный ответ.